# Algorithms for Compressed Sparse Rows

Tags: linear-algebra, sparse-matrix

Is there a general survey on the basic algorithms for the compressed sparse rows format (like transposition, multiplication, addition, ...)? While it is not hard to write effective algorithms for that, I am not aware of any comprehensive piece of writing on these algorithmic tasks.

This does not defy that many libraries already in existence perform these operations reasonable well.

addendum: The most efficient algorithms that I am aware of generally boil down to assembling (row,column,value) triplets from the input, and building a CSR structure from this.

Answer (score 4):

There are chapters on this in 
[Tim Davis' book](http://epubs.siam.org/doi/book/10.1137/1.9780898718881)
and [Yousef Saad's book](http://www-users.cs.umn.edu/~saad/IterMethBook_2ndEd.pdf) on linear systems for sparse matrices. Tim Davis also has some [lecture notes](http://www.cise.ufl.edu/research/sparse/sparse11/) on his website.